# babel + tableofcontents error: l.2 ...pter}{\chapternumberline {1}"Can I~get.."}{1}

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, babel

When I create chapter with name like "Can I~get.." ToC run into error.

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.2 ...pter}{\chapternumberline {1}"Can I~get.."}{1}
                                                  {}%
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg" was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.2 ...pter}{\chapternumberline {1}"Can I~get.."}{1}
                                                  {}%

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 2--2
 [][] []\T1/lmr/bx/n/10.95 "Can I get..  
! Leaders not followed by proper glue.
<to be read again> 
\hfill 
l.2 ...pter}{\chapternumberline {1}"Can I~get.."}{1}
                                                  {}%
)
```

```
\documentclass[oneside, 11pt]{memoir} % oneside - zarovnani doprostred sudych i lichych stranek
% WARNING!! - MEMOIR IS NOT COMPATIBLE WITH TITLESEC PACKAGE

\usepackage[czech]{babel} % základní podpora pro češtinu, mj. správné dělení slov

\begin{document}

    \newpage
    \chapter{"Can I~get.."}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: Write ``Can I get''. See also sec. 1.10 in the manual.

Comment: @JavierBezos Thank you. Could you tell me please, what manual do you mean? Babel, latex, memoir..? Thanks

Comment: I solved it by adding {} at the end of the chapter string

Comment: Sorry. The babel manual.